# How to automatically forward all network connections through a proxy?

Tags: proxy, transparent-proxy

I would like to forward all network connections of all applications through a proxy, even though the applications themselves may not have proxy support.

Is such a thing possible in desktop Ubuntu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use proxy connection as if it were Direct Connection](http://askubuntu.com/questions/280307/use-proxy-connection-as-if-it-were-direct-connection)

Answer (score 1):

[This response](https://superuser.com/questions/58261/forcing-all-outgoing-connections-through-proxies) on superuser.com recommends the [proxychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/howto.html) package, which enables you to send all TCP connections on a system through a proxy (or chain of proxies).